# Why does msft compare Interlocked.Increment(ref uniqueId) to zero?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I'm looking at the System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.Id implementation of .NET 4.0, and see the following code:

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public int Id
{
    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    get
    {
        if (this.m_taskSchedulerId == 0)
        {
            int num = 0;
            do
            {
                num = Interlocked.Increment(ref s_taskSchedulerIdCounter);
            }
            while (num == 0);
            Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.m_taskSchedulerId, num, 0);
        }
        return this.m_taskSchedulerId;
    }
}
```

why does msft compare the num==0 after the interlocked?    The implementation of **Interlocked.Increment()** says it returns the incremented value (after incrementing) so seems unnessicary to check for zero  (unless your counter wraps around, but if that happens you have bigger problems that are also not resolved here.

If I were to do it, i'd simply do:

```
public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                if(m_taskSchedulerId==0)
                {
                    var result = Interlocked.Increment(ref s_taskSchedulerIdCounter);
                    Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_taskSchedulerId, result, 0);
                }
                return m_taskSchedulerId;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe it's just a "belt and braces" approach. If the return value is, somehow, 0, then the `Id` would be re-generated (and probably non-0 this time) the next time `Id` was accessed - so the `Id` would change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> but if that happens you have bigger problems

No, that's the exact reason they do this.  From the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx):

```
public Int32 Id
{
    get
    {
        if (m_taskSchedulerId == 0)
        {
            int newId = 0;

            // We need to repeat if Interlocked.Increment wraps around and returns 0.
            // Otherwise next time this scheduler's Id is queried it will get a new value
            do
            {
                newId = Interlocked.Increment(ref s_taskSchedulerIdCounter);
            } while (newId == 0);

            Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_taskSchedulerId, newId, 0);
        }

        return m_taskSchedulerId;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the official reference!

seems like that id isn't truely meant to be unique then, which is why I assumed they must not care about wrap around.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The invariant is that `Id` never returns 0, because 0 is used internally to indicate that the value should be initialized. If `Id` was ever 0, the next time you queried it it would be a different value.